# How can I submit data with JQuery's Ajax class when my data name has a ":" in it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im using this essentially

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: send_email.php,
            type:'POST',
            data: {
            email: email_address,
            message: message
        },
        success: function(msg){
                alert('Email Sent');
        }                   
    });
}
});
```

But what can I do if one of my data names is something like `email:id`? That's equivalent to `email` in my case. What I want to do is submit something like `email:id : "10"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a plain JavaScript object, so all the rules of [JS objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) apply.

Putting stuff in quotes lets you get away with a lot of things, including characters such as `:` and spaces

```
 "email:id" : "10"
```